# imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring] No JPEG support in this PHP build

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, gd, jpeg

I am getting error mentioned in the subject when trying to upload in wordpress admin interface. 
My server's running nginx with php-fpm, PHP version is 5.3.0.

I've googled quite some regarding this problem but I wasn't able to find any solution. Is there a way to enable JPG support for GD without recompiling the PHP completely? (I've tried to follow that path but I can't get ./configure with all the needed to complete properly and I just don't have time to fix all the errors with all the libraries).

Thanks!

Comment: Tomalak's is probably the only answer. Have you considered using ImageMagick instead?

Comment: you're welcome. There's a patch here that doesn't look *too* terrible: http://return-true.com/2010/01/using-imagemagick-with-wordpress-2-9-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll have to recompile php.

Comment: thanks. i've just seen different hints that it could be done without that, but now I know it can't :)